# RecyclerView notifyItemChanged calls bind also on invisible cells

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a vertical `RecyclerView` with `LinearLayoutManager` with three item types and three different `ViewHolder`s.  It is a screen with comments, where first row is a post, rest are the comments and last one is an "infinity scrolling" loading row.

The first row with a post has a countdown, which I update every second via `notifyItemChanged(0, "countdown")`. The post is correctly updated, the `bind` is called with the correct payload. Below the post a one comment is visible only.

The problem is that this `notifyItemChanged(0, "countdown")` calls bind also for the invisible rows 2 and 3. If I update the layout of the post so two comments are visible, then only update for the invisible row 3 is called (plus bind with payload on the post). These binds are called without the payload, obviously. So it does full reload of the rows' data, which I do not want, it is a waste.

Now the funny thing, if I scroll the `RecyclerView` a tiny bit (even 1 px) this behaviour stops and just the first row, the post, is receiving the bind call. And when I scroll back to top the bind is not called for the invisible cells. So after a tiny scroll all this is fixed.

Other screen with posts only + infinity scrolling row does not behave like this and works as it should.

This is happening with `RecyclerView` from support library `27.0.2`.

**EDIT:**
This is happening with prefetch on and off, and with different values e.g. 2, 4.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: @eliamyro No solution yet. No one has responded and there is also no newer support library :(